# cron job return login page html in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, codeigniter-3

In my application i need to set cron job for daily updation. I am using CodeIgniter 3.0

My config.php file

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Here is my controller

```
class Cron extends CI_Controller {

public function cron_job(){
    if (!$this->input->is_cli_request()){
        echo 'test';
        //show_error('Direct access is not allowed');
    }
    else{
        echo 'call';
    }

    }
}
```

and i have set path in cpenal like

```
/usr/bin/php /home/public_html/my_app/index.php cron cron_job
```

But this return html of login page which is also front page of app.
I think there is issue with path, So how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two main differences between your code and my working CI3 cronjobs.

First is I use `if (is_cli())` instead of  `if (!$this->input->is_cli_request()){`.

Second, and may depend on your server settings but try adding **-cli** after **/usr/bin/php** as I have here:

```
/usr/bin/php-cli /home/public_html/index.php cron cron_job
```

Please let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

Just count check to make sure file name is the same as the controller class name.